# Are Xoom files automatically transferred to a newly added microSD card?

Tags: external-sd, motorola-xoom

I just slipped a 32G microSD card into my Xoom tablet. I had used the SD card in my Android smartphone before replacing that card with a larger capacity card. Are files that were heretofore stored on the Xoom automatically moved to the SD card?

I may have neglected to remove all files from the sd card before installing it... so I should be able to delete all files showing up in the /sdcard (sdcard) directory? I note I also have a folder named /mnt/external1 (sdcard) directory. Any idea what is what here?

Answer (score 1):

The files on the SD card are most likely there from the previous handset.  Android won't automatically move any files when it detects a new sd card.

Answer (score 1):

> Are files that were heretofore stored on the Xoom automatically moved to the SD card?

No, files that were already on your Xoom's storage aren't moved anywhere unless you manually choose to move them.

> I note I also have a folder named /mnt/external1 (sdcard) directory. Any idea what is what here?

The `/sdcard` directory is a portion of the Xoom's internal memory that is used as world-writeable storage. Since the Xoom uses MTP, it is not a physically separate partition like it might be on other devices, but it is treated differently than other portions of the internal storage (for example, it is accessible over USB).

`/mnt/external1` is the physical microSD card that you inserted into the Xoom. It exists and operates completely independently of the Xoom's internal storage (i.e. `/sdcard`). If you had any leftover files from your smartphone saved on your microSD card then they will should be in the `/mnt/external1` directory.

In other words, putting a microSD card in a Xoom effectively gives it *two* separate external storage locations.

Comment: On my stock 4.1.2 Xoom, I don't have write access to the MicroSD card (doesn't seem to be supported). Whenever I want to delete/add files I have to remove the card and put it into a computer. So you may need to do this to remove your smartphone files from the MicroSD card.